# How to return duplicate varbinary columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL 2008 table which lists some metadata for a bunch of files as follows:

ID bigint
FileName nvarchar(255)
FileHash varbinary(512)

FileHash is a SHA-512 hash of the file path in the FileName column.

Can I run a SELECT and return the FileNames which have the same FileHash?

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are having, or do you just want someone to write the query for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @Nezbit as Table ( Id BigInt Identity, FileName NVarChar(255), FileHash VarBinary(512) );

insert into @Nezbit ( FileName, FileHash ) values
  ( 'Bob', 0x1234 ),
  ( 'Carol', 0x5678 ),
  ( 'Ted', 0x9abc ),
  ( 'Alice', 0xdef0 ),
  ( 'Robert', 0x1234 ),
  ( 'Lydia', 0xdef0 );

select FileName, FileHash
  from @Nezbit as N
  where exists ( select 42 from @Nezbit where FileHash = N.FileHash and Id <> N.Id )
  order by FileHash, FileName;
```